# Can I use the same output directory for two projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have an MVC application that needs a timer job. As we all know, Web Applications are not really meant for that.

That is why I want to create another (console) application that does the required tasks needed. Because that application has to access Files from my WebApplication-Directory (local files) my preferred way would be to automatically build into the same /bin - directory as the web application. Can this be done?`

I am aware that I can move files Afterwards but whould prefer not to.

Comment: Use a Post-Build Event to copy the files from one output directory to the other. It's in the Project Properties window.

Comment: Change outputPath in Project Properties?

Comment: What kind of files are we talking about? Application files, or rather data files? Because it's generally considered good practice to not mix the two to begin with, doubly so if multiple applications are expected to have access to these files.

Comment: It's a bout the application files. The data file is a local LiteDB-Database used as bufferDB. The Timer is there to sync that data with the (slow) database

Comment: Use Hangfire.io for timed jobs.

Comment: I guess you can use hosted services and run your background tasks in your main app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice (we're using separate containers for deployment reasons, that's why I'm not sure if you can run them inside of a web app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good solution. You can: `1.` put these files into separate location out of both projects and put path to this folder into configs of both applications; or `2.` use 3rd party framework to run background jobs inside asp.net application like [quartz.net](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/), [hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io), [fluentscheduler](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler) etc.